# Informix - Efficiently find 10 most recent calls

Tags: sql, informix

I have a table that has data like calling number and timestamp.  I'd like find the ten most recent unique calls.  This SQL query works:

```
SELECT first 10 t.originatordn 
FROM 
     (SELECT DISTINCT a.originatordn,a.startdatetime AS time 
      FROM contactcalldetail a 
      WHERE originatordn <> '') t 
ORDER BY t.time DESC
```

The problem is this table has over 4 million records so it is very slow.  Is there a better way to do this query?

Comment: It would help if you showed an outline schema for the table, including any indexes on it.  The `<> ''` condition is not the same as `IS NOT NULL` — I'm not sure if that's going to matter to you (but why would you have call records where you don't know the originator number?).  Which version of Informix are you using, and on which platform?  Have you tried the OLAP (windowing) functionality?

Comment: It's possible for some callers to suppress their number.  Using IDS 11.70.UC7XA.  Schema is detailed [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cust_contact/contact_center/crs/express_11_6/reference/guide/UCCX_BK_CF9FAD2A_00_cisco-unified-ccx-database-schema/UCCX_BK_CF9FAD2A_00_cisco-unified-ccx-database-schema_chapter_00.html#reference_00B072ED66AECE0B7C626F71CE765FF3)  There are 2 indexes on this table.  Correct me if I'm wrong but I think OLAP functions are only available in IDS 12.

Comment: Yes, I think the OLAP functionality is in 12.10 only.  I assume an upgrade is out of the question (for this question, at any rate — you should be looking to upgrade soon).  There's a 4-part primary key which is presumably one of the two indexes.  What is the other index on?  You really need an index with the start time as the leading field to be able to get a good answer quickly — otherwise, the DBMS has to scan all 4 million or so records to come up with the answer, which is bound to be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Without an index I don't see how to make it fast. Therefore, I suggest creating an index if you don't have it already and run a simpler query that the SQL optimizer can execute by using an Index Only Scan.

```
create index ix1 on contactcalldetail (startdatetime, originatordn)

select 
    distinct originatordn as calling_number 
  from contactcalldetail
  where originatordn <> ''
  order by a.startdatetime desc
  limit 10
```

Comment: I tried installing Informix in my Debian server with no luck. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: No worries.  Thanks for your input.